# How do I check if an element is visible and check if the URL contains a string using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a URL that contains #gallery-carousel-3. When a user clicks on the right icon (.icon.icon-arrow-right) the .blockd class is added. That works fine. But when a user clicks on the left icon (.icon.icon-arrow-left) I would like to remove the .blockd class if the URL contains #gallery-carousel-3 and if the .panel-display div is visible. I can't seem to get the second part to work

My code is below:

```
      jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

            $('.icon.icon-arrow-right').click(function(){

              if(window.location.href.indexOf("#gallery-carousel-3") > -1 && $('.ad-panel').filter(':visible').length == 0 ) {
                $('.owl-wrapper-outer').addClass('blockd');

              }         

            });

            $('.icon.icon-arrow-left').click(function(){


              if(window.location.href.indexOf("#gallery-carousel-3") > -1 && $('.panel-display').is(':visible')) {
                $('.owl-wrapper-outer').removeClass('blockd');
              }            


            });
      });
```

Comment: Could you add an alert statement as `alert($('.panel-display').is(':visible'))` before the `if` condition `if(window.location.href.indexOf("#gallery-carousel-3") > -1 && $('.panel-display').is(':visible'))` to verify that `.panel-display` is indeed visible?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the hash (#) in the url using: `location.hash`

So, assuming your url is `http://example.com/#gallery-carousel-3`

```
var urlHash = location.hash; // => #gallery-carousel-3
```

Comment: I understand and location.hash returns the location.  I'm trying to figure out why      `if(window.location.href.indexOf("#gallery-carousel-3") > -1 && $('.panel-display').is(':visible'))` isn't working correctly

Comment: Ah, then open up your chrome dev tools and check which part of the `if()` is not passing. I suspect `$('.panel-display').is(':visible')` is not true

Comment: Ok I will check it out. This puts me on the right path